# Getting a Ruby "KeyError: key not found: 102" error when trying to maximize browser window using Selenium Webdriver v3.70

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've recently upgraded my Selenium Webdriver version to 3.70 and when I try to maximize the browser window, I get this error:

> KeyError: key not found: 102

Maximizing the window beforehand (on the previous version) seemed to be working absolutely fine, I'm not sure if it's just a coincidence though as it isn't a standard type of Selenium error.

Here's my code:

```
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
  $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :profile => profile
  $driver.manage.window.maximize
```

Anyone else having this problem? Also worth noting I'm using Ruby v2.3.1, so perhaps that needs updating? I just didn't want to make loads of drastic updates, but wanted the latest Selenium Webdriver version. I also don't know whether it's chromedriver related, but last updated this to the latest version on 19/09/17.

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: does the version of chromedriver you're using support the version of chrome that you're using?

Comment: Hi, yeah it does. I had that problem before but upgraded accordingly. Those versions haven't changed since the webdriver update. Cheers,

Comment: is there a stacktrace you can include in your message?  it might help

Comment: I just ran it again with extra logging and it exceeds the comment char limit for here, what's the best way to get this to you? Sorry it's my first time asking a question on here so don't know if there's an easy way.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware I don't know if there's an easier way, but it can be found here: https://shrib.com/#_9m-GbXVhhsvlnjkwKO4

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow Dan.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask explains how you can ask effective questions.  scanning that stacktrace, I don't know how to help you.  It's been ages since I used Ruby.  generically, though, you should look at that one line of code in your hooks.rb file that's referenced...perhaps there's a clue there.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed with my hooks.rb since the Selenium Webdriver upgrade, so the problem persists :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upgrade `chromedriver` to `2.33`.

On Mac you can upgrade it via brew `brew upgrade chromedriver`

Comment: I ran into a ruby version error when I ran upgrade the first time. I ran it again and it worked the second time. Just wanted to throw that out there in case anyone ran into the same thing.

Comment: I was using [chromedriver-helper](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper) gem so needed to run `chromedriver-update 2.35`

Comment: You're my savior.